google.protobuf.any variable put in to int array in C++
`Hi, I have a variable called mapData in google.protobuf.any type. how would I put that mapData infoamtion in to an int array in in C++. I am using proto3 syntax.
Appreciate some help on this
Thank you,
     message A{
     uint32 id;
    google.protobuf.Any mapData ;
    }

    std::array<uint32,10> data;
    uint32 varID = message.id;
    data[0] = message.mapData;//get compile error  - cannot convert google.protobuf.Any to                            std:array<uint32,10, 10> in assignment

`

google.protobuf.Any holds messages, not ints or arrays of ints.

how would I extract the messages ? is there a way to know what type the messages are? type_url() -is this the type or 1 message?

google::protobu::Any has an Is function template so you can determine the type and an UnpackTo function to unpack it.  The documentation has an example.

when using google.protobuf.any PackTo and UnpackTo, how to I send a uint32_t array of 5 elements? PackTo and Unpack to takes a google protobuf Message typ. How would I convert uint32_t array to Message type?

Like I said in my first comment, google.protobuf.Any holds messages, not ints or arrays of ints.  You'll need to define a message type that has a repeated integer field if you want to put an array of ints into an Any.
